# How I can setup multiple factory types in Lumen 7.x

Tags: lumen, factories

I want to setup multiple factories for my user model (e.g. admin). I followed the docs and tried it with 'defineAs': https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/testing. But it seems that this way is no longer available: https://github.com/illuminate/database/commit/f07d290e75983ccbc51379b88181b7df9cb70ca0. Is there an alternative way?!

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to use defineAs, you actually just need to re-arrage the define function, something like

```
$factory->define('App/User', function (Faker $faker) use ($factory) {
    $user = $factory->raw('App/User');

    return array_merge($user, ['admin' => true]);
}, 'admin');
```

edit:
looks like I also have some issue when I need to call said factory to use it with actingAs on phpunit, so I make some workaround

on factories I make something like

```
$factory->define('App/User', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
    ];
});
```

and on the test I call it with

```
$admin = factory('App/User')->create([
    'admin' => true
]);

$this->actingAs($admin)->post('/login', ['username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin'])
```

still, if anyone can give example to have multiple factories will be better